# ElasticSearch - search by property from concrete index while going through multiple indexes

Tags: elasticsearch

We're using ElasticSearch and we have two different indexes with different data. Recently, we wanted to make a query that needs data from both indexes. ES allows to search through multiple indexes: `/index1,index2/_search`. The problem is that both indexes have properties with the same name and there could be collisions because ES doesn't know on which index to search.

How can we tell ES to look up a property from concrete index?
For example: `index1.myProperty` and `index2.otherProperty`

Comment: does the example in https://discuss.elastic.co/t/multi-index-search-multiple-queries-within-the-query/119564 help?